# How to use Horde/Imap_Client with Yii Framework

Tags: yii, imap, plesk, horde

I'm trying to figure out how can I use Horde Imap Client library in order to import emails in my Yii Framework application but I don't know how to install and load it.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps:

1) Make sure you've got PEAR installed in your machine/server

2) Install Horde horde_imap_client as the docs say http://dev.horde.org/imap_client/install.php

```
pear channel-discover pear.horde.org
pear install horde/horde_imap_client
```

3) Install Horde Autoloader because it is not installed by default

```
pear install horde/horde_autoloader
```

4) Require the autoloader before loading Yii

```
require_once 'Horde/Autoloader/Default.php';
```

You can do it in the entry script index.php and optionally in yiic.php if you're planning to use the library from Yii console commands.

5) Now you should be able to do this from a controller or Yii command:

```
try {
    $imap = new Horde_Imap_Client_Socket(array(
        'username' => 'user@example.com',
        'password' => 'pwd',
        'hostspec' => 'mail.example.com',
        'port' => 993,
        'secure' => 'ssl',
    ));

    $query = new Horde_Imap_Client_Search_Query();
    $results = $imap->search('INBOX', $query);
    var_dump($results['match']);

} catch (Horde_Imap_Client_Exception $e) {
    // Any errors will cause an Exception.
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

6) Last note:

If you're using Plesk panel on your server you'll have problems loading PEAR libraries because of open_basedir restriction, so you have to add your PEAR path (/usr/share/pear) to open_basedir setting. Depending on the version of Plesk, for older versions you must do it with vhost.conf file like this posts says: http://www.smerret.com/computers/linux/control-panels/using-pear-with-plesk and for newer Plesk versions you can do it directly from the Plesk Panel going to the domain's PHP Configuration and looking for open_basedir setting.